# Free touch big electrodes (arduino zero)

Tags: arduino-zero

I want to try making big electrodes 20cm*1 cm
but i got an effect i dont understand.
In the picture red and blue are the diffrent electrodes
at first touch the blue  one and it rises.
then i touched the red  one and it rises.
when i touch both electrodes both signals dropps ??
when itouch both with gloves both rise ??

i think its not allowed to touch the pure cooper

Also i would like to know whats the output from the mesure funktion of the  free touch libary  (physical dimension ,like time or voltage??)

```
#include "Adafruit_FreeTouch.h"

Adafruit_FreeTouch qt_2 = Adafruit_FreeTouch(A1, OVERSAMPLE_4, RESISTOR_50K, FREQ_MODE_NONE);
Adafruit_FreeTouch qt_3 = Adafruit_FreeTouch(A2, OVERSAMPLE_4, RESISTOR_50K, FREQ_MODE_NONE);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("FreeTouch test");
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);


  if (! qt_2.begin())  
    Serial.println("Failed to begin qt on pin A1");
  if (! qt_3.begin())  
    Serial.println("Failed to begin qt on pin A2");

}



void loop() {
  int counter,result2,result3, result = 0;


  counter = millis();
  result = qt_2.measure(); 
  result2=result;

  counter = millis();
  result = qt_3.measure(); 
  result3=result;
    Serial.print(result2);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.println(result3);
  delay(200);
}
```

[image]

[image]

---

the problem was that i touch de the electrodes on the copperside instead for the rearside

Comment: You need to provide more information. How have you wired the electrodes to the Arduino? Which library do you mean (provide a link to it)? And please show your code in your question. You can edit your question by clicking the "edit" link under it

Comment: is there a way using mutalcapactiance sensors without the qtouch lib   or do i have to use atmelstudio to use qtouch on my arduino zero